# Center Containter vertically in JSX react-bootstrap format

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to center the container on the x and y axis but my code is only working for the x axis. Any ideas on how I could get it working on the y axis aswell (Vertically)?

```
function App() {
 return (
<Container className="align-content-center flex-wrap">
  <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <h1>Convert</h1>
  </Row>
  <CurrencyRow />
  <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center">=</Row>
  <CurrencyRow />
</Container>
 );
  }
```

Comment: What do you think those classes are doing....?

Comment: @Paulie_D The Row classes are centered on the x-axis as I wanted but it does not apply to the y axis thats the reason I do not know which is why I'm here

Comment: You're using flexbox to align the contents of the container and rows..so i suggest you use the same on the parent of the container.

Comment: @Paulie_D the className "align-content-center flex-wrap" is not working. the Container class is the root. It does not have a parent

Comment: Of course it does the body is a parent is it not?